# XGBoost Python: XGBoostError: we need weight to evaluate ams

Tags: python, xgboost

i am trying to use XGBoost package in Python
I have this error when running this code

```
import xgboost as xgb
data=np.array(traindata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels=np.array(traindata['Category'].cat.codes)

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data, label=labels)

param = {'bst:max_depth':6, 'bst:eta':0.5, 'silent':1, 'objective':'multi:softprob' }
param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'mlogloss'
param['lambda'] = 1
param['num_class']=39

evallist  = [(dtrain,'train')]

plst = param.items()
plst += [('eval_metric', 'ams@0')]

num_round = 10
bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist )

bst.save_model('0001.model')
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        17 
>        18 num_round = 10
>   ---> 19 bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist )
>        20 
>        21 bst.save_model('0001.model')
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.pyc
>   in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize,
>   early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates,
>   xgb_model)
>       122             nboost += 1
>       123             if len(evals) != 0:
>   --> 124                 bst_eval_set = bst.eval_set(evals, i, feval)
>       125                 if isinstance(bst_eval_set, STRING_TYPES):
>       126                     msg = bst_eval_set
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.pyc
>   in eval_set(self, evals, iteration, feval)
>       753             _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterEvalOneIter(self.handle, iteration,
>       754                                                   dmats, evnames, len(evals),
>   --> 755                                                   ctypes.byref(msg)))
>       756             return msg.value
>       757         else:
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.pyc
>   in _check_call(ret)
>        95     """
>        96     if ret != 0:
>   ---> 97         raise XGBoostError(_LIB.XGBGetLastError())
>        98 
>        99
>
> XGBoostError: we need weight to evaluate ams

i don't see anything about it in the docs

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When computing the ams metric, you need to have a weight for each labeled training point. You set the weights by using the keyword argument weight when creating your DMatrix. A simple example.

```
weights = np.ones(len(labels))
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data, label = labels, weight = weights)
```

And an in-depth example from a recent Kaggle competition: https://github.com/tqchen/xgboost/blob/master/demo/kaggle-higgs/higgs-numpy.py.